# Extending script with standalones whilst keeping global space clean

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm struggling with how solve this.

I have some scripts:

1. A simple plotter, for painting graphs on canvas.
2. A logger, post and get logs by XMLHttpRequest.
3. A cookie-handler, general cookie handler.
4. A IndexedDB script for saving and loading images.

They all work and can be used independently. Are self-contained and are kept in separate files.

They have a layout like:

```
var Plotter = (function () {
    'use strict';
    function Plotter (opt) {

    }

    Plotter.prototype.fun1 () {}
    Plotter.prototype.fun2 () {}

    return Plotter;
})();
```

---

Now I have a script where I combine these and in addition do a lot of other stuff.

```
var my_app = function () {
    this.init = function () {

    }
    this.fun2 = function () {
        this.plotter = new Plotter(opt);
        ...
    }
    this.fun3 = function () { }
};
```

---

What I would like is to design this in such a way that I do not have to pollute the global environment with nothing but `my_app`.

I do not want `MyPlotter`, `MyLogger` etc as global variables, but as:

```
my_app = function () {
    var Plot = Plotter;
    ...
    this.fun2 = function () {
        this.plotter = new Plot(opt);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?

In essence extend `my_app` with the other scripts whilst at the same time keeping the global space unpolluted.

It is perhaps OK when one have two or three extra globals, but not when it becomes much more as in 10-20,.. I do not even like to have two. Would stay at the one.

I obviously have to change things, but a main thing is to continue to keep the files separate such that I can use e.g. `Logger` in a separate project.
 It is easy solved with serverside code to generate a combined space for `my_app` and the separate scripts, but would rather like to not do it this way.

---

#### Edit:

After looking at [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181979/2148245) I guess I go for a variant of that for now. Believe perhaps I'm going to use a library of sorts, as in:

```
if ('Library' in global) {
    global.Library.Plotter = Plotter;
} else {
    global.Plotter = Plotter;
}
```

And then in `my_app` say:

```
this.Plott = new Library.Plotter();
```

It still leaves me with two globals, which is one more then I'd like, (I'm perhaps being stupid here), but then it would not be coupled to one name. An even better solution would perhaps be to always say:

```
if ('Library' in global) {
    global.Library.Plotter = Plotter;
} else {
    global.Library = {Plotter:Plotter};
}
```

This way it would be consistent across scripts. (Ouch, it looks so stupidly simple now.)

I know It is not what I asked, but it is perhaps a better way to do it after all. It is a design issue, and I am far from comfortable on if I'm doing it right.

Comment: So when you use the `Plotter` script own its own, you want a `Plotter` global; but when used with other scripts as `my_app`, you want only the `my_app` global with `Plotter` (et. al.) as properties?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes. I believe so. Know that is vague answer, but my Javascripts are rather simple and I have no way to have an concrete opinion on it. I have read on books like [this one](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), but having a hard time finding good design patterns for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
(function (global) {
    'use strict';
    function Plotter (opt) {

    }

    Plotter.prototype.fun1 () {}
    Plotter.prototype.fun2 () {}

    if ('my_app' in global) {
        global.my_app.Plotter = Plotter;
    }
    else {
        global.Plotter = Plotter;
    }
})(this);
```

If you want to combine things into `my_app`, start off with a script that defines `my_app` in the global namespace as an object:

```
var my_app = {};

// or
this.my_app = {};
```

If you want to use `Plotter` on its own, don't, and it will create the `Plotter` global.

Comment: TJ, could you use `global.my_app` instead of `'my_app' in global`? Is it just a preference?

Comment: This seems to work nice. I tried something similar, but then I tried to ***extend*** `my_app` with `Plotter` instead of adding it as an sub-unit. That became more complex then wanted. But I'll try this further. Have to work on it, – but this seems like a good way. Or, that said, would you call it a good design?

Comment: @Zimzalabim: It's up to you. I think I'd probably have the names not change whether I was using `Plotter` standalone or not. So rather than `my_app` (which I assume varied by app), I'd just have `Zimlib` or similar and then it would always be `Zimlib.Plotter` whether used on its own or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, That's how I did it as per my update in Q. Found [this link](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) as well that show some interesting and nice ways of extending across files etc.